# Input dimension of Pytorch CNN model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I have input data for my 2D CNN model, say; `X_train` with shape `(torch.Size([716, 50, 50])`

my model is:

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=4,stride=1,padding = 1)
        self.mp1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4,stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size=4,stride =1)
        self.mp2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4,stride=2)
        self.fc1= nn.Linear(2304,256)
        self.dp1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)
        x = F.relu(self.mp1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.mp2(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(in_size,-1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dp1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

but when I run the model, I always get this error:
`---> x = F.relu(self.mp1(self.conv1(x)))`

```
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 1, 4, 4], but got 3-dimensional input of size [64, 50, 50] instead
```

I understand my input for the model is of size 64 (batch size), 50*50 (size of each input, in this case is signal picture).

But I don't understand why it still requires `4-dimensional input` where I had set my `in_channels` for `nn.Conv2d` to be 1.

How to solve this input dimension problem or to change the dimension requirement of model input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether `in_channels` is `1` or `42` does not matter: it is still an added dimension. It is useful to read [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) in this respect.

In- and output are of the form N, C, H, W

- N: batch size
- C: channels
- H: height in pixels
- W: width in pixels

So you need to [add the dimension](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html#torch.unsqueeze) in your case:

```py
# Add a dimension at index 1
x = x.unsqueeze(1)
```

Comment: many thanks, the `unsqueeze` is what I need

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem...
You've entered the `in_channels=1`, That doesn't mean that It doesn't exists...
Expanding the Dimension of Your Data to [64, 1, 50, 50] should solve your problem

use [.view()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html) on input tensor